# How does hash_set::upper_bound() work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hashset

How does Visual C++'s [`stdext::hash_set<T>::upper_bound()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b0yfz55.aspx) work?
How can a hashtable also keep elements sorted?!

I've tried to read the source code but it's hard to decipher the STL code... and even conceptually, I can't make sense out of it: how can a hashtable compare elements?

Comment: Presumably the algorithm runs in linear time rather than logarithmic.

Comment: I think it has to do with compatibility with `multiset`, where `lower_bound(x)` and `upper_bound(x)` gives the beginning and end of the range returned by `equal_range(x)`. A reasonable interpretation would be that it returns an iterator to the element after the matched element (as `lower_bound` would give an iterator to the element), and the end of the container when the element is not a member of the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various `unordered_xxx` templates use a hash function to sort objects into buckets. Objects that go into the same bucket are grouped so that objects that compare equal are adjacent (where "compare equal" means "`a < b` is false and `b < a` is false, or, for the predicate version, `pr(a,b)` is false and `pr(b,a)` is false"). `lower_bound()` returns an iterator that points to the first object that matches the passed value; `upper_bound()` returns an iterator that's one past the last object that matches the passed value. There's no global sorting involved.

Answer (score -1):

A hashtable doesn't need to keep the elements sorted; it merely has to compare any newly inserted element with the current highest value and update accordingly. No need to sort.

As to how it can compare elements: that's what operators are for. As long as the type <T> implements the '>' operator it can be sorted. You can write your own > operator for your class, though it must support strict ordering (e.g., when comparing "abc" against "abcdef" you must decide which one is 'larger' in this case).

Comment: The default ordering in STL is `less(T,T)`, not `more(T,T)`.